# how to find id of layout in a Bitmap Button java source that I made

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I made a Bitmap button that has an animation effect on a layout 
but it cannot find the id of the layout and it says it indicates Null point

Here is my source below

```
public class BitmapButton extends Button{

public BitmapButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public BitmapButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init(){
   setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selector);

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        boolean selected=true;
        Animation anim;

        LinearLayout layout_search = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_search);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(selected) {
                setSelected(true);
                anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.translate_down);
                ***layout_search.startAnimation(anim);***
                layout_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                selected =!selected;
            }
            else{
                setSelected(false);
                anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.translate_up);
                layout_search.startAnimation(anim);
                layout_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                selected =!selected;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

=========================================================================
`layout_search.startAnimation(anim);`

from here it gets wrong saying

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.widget.LinearLayout.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)` on a null object reference

I know findViewById method in Button Class is different from the one in the MainActivity but I just dont know then, how I can find the LinearLayout linear_search?? with this problem I can make the anim effection on this button.
plz let me know...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class BitmapButton extends Button{

    public BitmapButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BitmapButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
       setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selector);

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            boolean selected=true;
            Animation anim;

          // _____________ just commented out this line ______________ 
  //  LinearLayout layout_search = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layout_search);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

    // i simply add this line here and add view v before findViewById
     LinearLayout layout_search = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layout_search);


                if(selected) {
                    setSelected(true);
                    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.translate_down);
                    ***layout_search.startAnimation(anim);***
                    layout_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    selected =!selected;
                }
                else{
                    setSelected(false);
                    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.translate_up);
                    layout_search.startAnimation(anim);
                    layout_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    selected =!selected;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout_search = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_search);
```

From documentation:

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

You trying to search layout inside button. Try to use getParent().findViewById
if you want to start animation on parent of button.